# Traffic difference between sub-domain.example.com AND example.com/sub-domain

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, traffic, visitors

It is possible to create sub-domains for a website in these two ways:

```
sub-domain.example.com
example.com/sub-domain
```

`example.com` is the main website.

Between the above implementations is there any difference in visiting and traffic statistics for the main website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-domain.example.com is a separate site from example.com. This means that any traffic for sub-domain.example.com will not be reflected in example.com. However, example.com/sub-domain would be part of example.com and therefore the traffic would be reflected in example.com This fact is dictated by the web server.

Comment: Is it possible to reflect this rating to the `example.com` ?

Comment: @Drupalist I read in your question that you were talking about traffic. Are you taking about rank?

Comment: Upper traffic meaning the better rank, is not it? We have a website with multiple sub domains and we need to aggregate the visitors statistics of all of them to the main website.

Comment: @Drupalist Google, Bing and others cannot really gauge your traffic therefore there is no *DIRECT* correlation to rank, however the effect is that the more popular your site becomes, the more metrics that Google and Bing can gauge will increase the better your rank. Rank lags behind traffic, but traffic ultimately will effect rank- to what degree depends on too many factors to really know. I am not a big fan of sub-domains as in sub-domain.example.com because you are dividing your traffic over several sites. I prefer example.com/sub-domain.